# How to get an If Statement to Manupulate Variables

Tags: php

I am writing a simple test case to manipulate various groups of variables so as to
achieve a few specific results, but I need a ‘third eye’ to see what I am doing
wrong.  I am not getting the expecting results as stated below.

```
Sample Code:

$this->_default['method'] = 'index';

// Input-
// Group one var Option:
$pMethod = 'mission';
$arg1    = 'NULL';
$arg2    = 'NULL';
$arg3    = 'NULL';

// Group two var Option:
$pMethod = 'mission-statements-p_2';;
$arg1    = 'NULL';
$arg2    = 'NULL';
$arg3    = 'NULL';

// Group three var Option:
$pMethod = 'mission';
$arg1    = 'mission-statements-p_2';
$arg2    = 'NULL';
$arg3    = 'NULL';


if ($pMethod && $pMethod !== $this->_default['method'])
{

$find = 'p_';
$pos1  = strpos($pMethod, $find);
$pos2  = strpos($arg1, $find);


if ($pos1 !== false)
{ 
    list($arg1,$arg2)= explode("-p_",$pMethod);
    $method = 'page';
    $arg1 = !empty($arg1) ? $arg1 : NULL;
    $arg2 = !empty($arg2) ? $arg2 : NULL;
    $arg3 = NULL;

}
else if ($pos1 === false && $pos2 !== false)
{
    list($arg2,$arg3)= explode("-p_",$arg1);
    $method = 'page';
    $arg1 = $pMethod;
        $arg2 = !empty($arg2) ? $arg2 : NULL;
        $arg3 = !empty($arg3) ? $arg3 : NULL;
    }
}
else 
{
$method = $pMethod;
    $arg1 = !empty($arg1) ? $arg1 : NULL;
    $arg2 = !empty($arg2) ? $arg2 : NULL;
    $arg3 = NULL;
}


// The expecting output results should be:

// Group one var Option: no changes

// Group two var Option:
$pMethod = 'page';
$arg1    = 'mission-statements';
$arg2    = 2;
$arg3    = 'NULL';

// Group three var Option:
$pMethod = 'page';
$arg1    = 'mission';
$arg2    = 'mission-statements';
$arg3    = 2;
```

Comment: You only need `!="` and `==` rather than `!==` and `===`.

Comment: @BeatAlex Both the operands are strings. So no problem with that.

Comment: @KevinPaladin, saves time though!

Answer (score 1):

You are testing `!empty($arg1)` where `$arg1` was defined as `$arg1 = 'NULL';`, which [will not evaluate to empty](http://www.php.net/empty), as it is the string `'NULL'` which is not considered empty, instead of the `NULL` constant, which is.

To fix, change your definitions to omit the strings:

```
$arg1 = NULL; 
// etc...
```

You also don't need to repeat these definitions, you're mostly overwriting them with the values that they have:

```
// Input-
// Group one var Option:
$pMethod = 'mission';
$arg1    = 'NULL';
$arg2    = 'NULL';
$arg3    = 'NULL';

// Group two var Option:
$pMethod = 'mission-statements-p_2';;
$arg1    = 'NULL'; // These
$arg2    = 'NULL'; // Are
$arg3    = 'NULL'; // Redundant
```

Comment: That's a good catch about the <pre><code>$arg1 = NULL;</code></pre>. Thanks guys!